# Framework7 DOM Manipulation

Tags: javascript, html, dom, html-framework-7

I'd like to reconfigure or change the way Framework7 uses the DOM. Preferably so it does not inject the code of said pages into the already loaded DOM. Is there a way I can go about doing this? I enjoyed JQueryMobile and how it differed from the way Framework7 uses DOM. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: can you provide an example of what you're looking for ? Do you mean, DOM event manipulation (with JQuery for JQueryMobile / Dom7 with framework7) or page loading which can be made by different ways in Framework7 ?

Comment: @NLAMY page loading to be more specific

Comment: and what behavior are you looking for exactly ? Are you facing performance issues in injecting pages ? To my mind, it is a best practice to use a single-page pattern in a mobile html app

Comment: @NLAMY No, the issue that prompted me to ask this question was. Let me explain. I have an app, and you click something within it, that loads view.html (I'm using NodeJS) and when I try to put an Adsense ad in the view.html page it seems to never show up. http://iNoJB.net/app is where you can see an example. Click an image and it loads view.html, but trying to put an an within the page does nothing. My assumption is something with FW7 and how it uses the DOM.

Comment: thanks for explanation, for my curiosity, do you use Node.JS on this frontend or in the backend ? can you please provide dom injection code to see where it is located ?

Comment: @NLAMY It is in the backend. It simply loads view.html in a new connection (NodeJS) and puts the icon, comments, ect from the database into the view.html. I apologize in advance, I am considerably new to NodeJS. I really enjoy it's speed in comparison to PHP so I decided to learn something new.

Comment: I'm using Node.JS too on my mobile app backend. It's not related to your question but why are you using Node.JS to deserve html (I imagine you're using a template engine like twig or another) rather than using it like a REST server and doing your dom manipulation only in your frontend ? In case of a web application this make sense but for a mobile app this will use "lot" of bandwidth, no ? In your example, where can we see insertion code of adsense block ?

Comment: @NLAMY I removed the Adsense code since it just made a big blank block. And it is a web app.

Comment: Ok, so If I understand, you didn't succed in injecting at runtime (with Dom7) html content to your view.html page injected after an ajax call ?

Comment: @NLAMY Yes, do you suggest anything else?

Comment: How do you inject content of view.html ? I see your adsense in tab 2 and 3

Comment: @NLAMY Yes those are just placed directly in the HTML. All in one file. But, the view.html is separate from that. It's a separate page.

Comment: Yes but how do you inject it ? With Dom7 ?

Comment: @NLAMY would this be easier in email?

Comment: Can you just post your inclusion code ?